# Examples for "flach" meant as = ohne [gedankliche] Tiefe und daher nichtssagend, unwesentlich; oberflächlich, banal

Tags: word-usage

I looked for the meaning of [*flach* on Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/flach) and I understood most of it.

Just the forth and last meaning is for me not clear and I am not sure exactly about how to use *flach* in that way.

> Flach = ohne [gedankliche] Tiefe und daher nichtssagend, unwesentlich; oberflächlich, banal

Can you write me some other examples in which *flach* can be used with that meaning?

Comment: Not directly an answer, but the word "Flachzange" is used jokingly for a not-so-clever person: http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-bedeutet-flachzange-wenn-man-es-auf-menschen-bezieht

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hear a speech from a politician. Then you could say

> *Die Rede war flach*

That would mean, that the person was speaking without saying anything or without giving proper information.

It is also common to say:

> *Der war aber flach*

If somebody told a very poor and easy joke. I dunno, if a joke can be easy, i mean, that this kind of joke is very trivial and people don't need to think about it.

Comment: If your wife rolls her eyes on your joke you can almost always be sure it was *flach*... :-)

Answer (score 1):

In English you would say "shallow". A different, but similar, metaphor.

Comment: Gefragt waren weitere Beispiele, keine Übersetzung.

Answer (score 1):

Der Witz war flach.

Das System meint, meine Antwort sei zu flach mit 19 Zeichen, also noch dieser selbstbezügliche, etwas längere Text. Tiefer wird es damit aber auch nicht.